# Html element "Frame src" click through code

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, c#-4.0

Looking for your views on this:

Is It possible to click the src of frame through code(preferably in C# windows application).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "click" do you mean open the frame's source URL?

Comment: uhh I cant begin to start and answer this question without more explanation.....

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking for.I tried element.InvokeMember("click"); its not working.//"IDXVTB" is a frame
  HtmlElement element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("IDXVTB");
element.InvokeMember("click");

Comment: How "Click url" is differnt from "tickle url" or "smell url"? :) You can get url (IFrame's "src" attribute as StriplingWarrior points out) but it is unclear what you planning to do with it later.

Comment: Hi let me put it this way. In my windows application I need to fetch some information from web.For this I am using webbrowser, I want these steps to be managed through code .login to site there after need to click a menu which is a frame with uri as its src.I looged in successfully and when i tried to click the frame using webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("IDXVTB"); element.InvokeMember("click");  Its not working!! now my ques is shall I try some other ways to get it done? Hope I am clear .thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use javascript to get the value of the src attribute off the frame element, and then set `window.location` to that value.

Comment: +1 for good attempt to guess the question... Note that with JavaScript you get "Access Denied" if page and IFrame are on different domains.